# How can I speed up summing an array of structs grouped by two properties - macOS Swift

Tags: swift

The code I am using is shown below but seems very slow to calculate the sum - around 20 seconds.  Any suggestions for how to speed this up ?

Actually its a bit more complicated since I need to create a fine result object that includes all the original properties and the count updated to the sum.

```
struct PAData: Equatable, Hashable {
        let pCode: String
        let aCode: String
        let otherProperty1: String // Unique to pCode
        let otherProperty2: String // Unique to pCode
        let count: Int
        
        static func == (lhs: PAData, rhs: PAData) -> Bool {
                return
                    lhs.pCode == rhs.pCode &&
                    lhs.aCode == rhs.aCode
            }
        func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
                hasher.combine(pCode)
                hasher.combine(aCode)
            }
}

// Group by aCode and pCode and sum count
func calcSum() {
    // Find the unique records based on pCode/aCode properties - very fast takes 0.1 second
    let unique = Set<PAData>(paData)

    // Now find the sum for each pCode/aCode group  - too slow takes 20 seconds to complete - how to speed this up ?
    // Really only needs to be done for those that have more than one record !??
    for key in unique {
                
        let sum = paData.filter({$0.pCode == key.pCode && $0.aCode == key.aCode}).map({$0.count}).reduce(0, +)

        let summary = PAData(pCode: key.pCode, aCode: key.aCode, count: sum)

        resultArray.append(summary)
    }
}
```

It seems that using Dictionary.grouping() is fast but then combining the results is slow again - still taking some 35 seconds.

```
struct PAData: Equatable, Hashable {
    let pCode: String
    let aCode: String
    let count: Int

    var key: String {
        return pCode + ":" + aCode
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: PAData, rhs: PAData) -> Bool {
            return
                lhs.pCode == rhs.pCode &&
                lhs.aCode == rhs.aCode
        }
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
            hasher.combine(pCode)
            hasher.combine(aCode)
        }
}

    // Group by aCode and pCode and sum count
    func calcSum() {
        var grouped = Dictionary(grouping: paData, by:{$0.key})

        
        struct Item {
            let key: String
            let sum: Int
        }

        let resultArray = grouped.keys.map { (key) -> Item in
            let value = grouped[key]!
            return Item(key: key, sum: value.map{$0.facings}.reduce(0, +))
        }  
        
        // Find the unique records based on pCode/aCode properties - very fast takes 0.1 second
        let unique = Set<PAData>(paData)

        // Now we need to combined so we have the original properties as well as the sum but no duplicates - slow
        let results = unique.map({ rec -> PAData in
            let sum = resultArray.first(where: {$0.key == rec.key})?.sum ?? rec.facings
            return PAData(brandCode: rec.brandCode, assortmentCode: rec.assortmentCode, productCode: rec.productCode, productCategory: rec.productCategory, productDescription: rec.productDescription, facings: sum)
        })
  }
```

Comment: What about using `Dictionary.grouping()` and iterate over values to sum?

Comment: @Larme - yes I just discovered that but it doesn't seem to solve the problem - I will update my question since I left that part out

Comment: You aren't uniquing. by `aCode` & `pCode`. Test it, `unique.count` == `paData.count`. That's why it's taking time. Also, in `sum` calculation, you are iterating over paData with filter (so it you have 1k elements...), then iterating overt the result (map, so if you found 100 elements matching), and then with the reduce you iterate on the same count (100)

Comment: no my unique.count != paData.count 
"records: 17797   unique: 17363" - which is about right.
Typically there will only be one or two of the same record - perhaps as many as 10.

Comment: Sad thing is this is only required for about 400 records - but I can't think of a way to filter out so just the duplicates need to be recalculated. Ah maybe the grouped by where the element count > 1 !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
func calcSum2(_ paData: [PAData]) -> [PAData] {
    let date = Date()
    let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: paData) { aPaData in
        return PAData(pCode: aPaData.pCode, aCode: aPaData.aCode, count: -2) //Here it's to take advantage of your Hashable
    }
    let resultArray = grouped.compactMap { (key: PAData, values: [PAData]) -> PAData in
        let sum = values.reduce(into: 0, { $0 += $1.count })
        return PAData(pCode: key.pCode, aCode: key.aCode, count: sum)
    }
    return resultArray
}
```

What's wrong with your code:

```
let unique = Set<PAData>(paData)
for key in unique {
            
    let sum = paData.filter({$0.pCode == key.pCode && $0.aCode == key.aCode}).map({$0.count}).reduce(0, +)

    let summary = PAData(pCode: key.pCode, aCode: key.aCode, count: sum)

    resultArray.append(summary)
}
```

Could be changed into:

```
let unique = Set<PAData>(paData)
for key in unique {
            
    let filtered = paData.filter({$0.pCode == key.pCode && $0.aCode == key.aCode})
    let countMap = filtered.map({$0.count})
    let sum = countMap.reduce(0, +)

    let summary = PAData(pCode: key.pCode, aCode: key.aCode, count: sum)

    resultArray.append(summary)
}
```

So if you have 10k elements, and 1k elements for each with the same pCode & aCode.

- filtered: 10k iteration (you iterate over all `pData`)
- countMap: 1k iteration (you iterate over all `filtered`)
- reduceInto: 1k iteration (you iterate over all `countMap`)

-> Repeat for each unique

You see the lost calculations?

But if you grouped as in my suggested solution, you are grouping, so you don't need the filter anymore.
And I summed and mapped in the same iteration, which in your case might be:
`let sum = filtered.reduce(into: 0, { $0 += $1.count })`. In the sample of count I gave, it's 1k iteration saved per unique.

Now, one of the issue I got, is that `unique` isn't making unique per `aCode` & `pCode` on my sample code (I don't know why)., it doesn't seem to work as it should be. I don't know why yet (I might edit the question on why), but that's still be less optimized, because you'd still filter each time. In theory, you should use `$0 == key` in your `filter` since you override the equal method to not take in account the `count`.

Sample test on my side:

```
let testArray = [PAData(pCode: "a", aCode: "b", count: 2),
                 PAData(pCode: "a", aCode: "b", count: 3),
                 PAData(pCode: "d", aCode: "c", count: 2)]
let setTest = Set<PAData>(testArray)

print("setTest: \(setTest)")
let groupTest = Dictionary(grouping: testArray) { aPaData in
    return PAData(pCode: aPaData.pCode, aCode: aPaData.aCode, count: -2)
}
print("groupTest: \(groupTest)")
```

With strange result:

```
Dictionary:
{
    "PAData(pCode: \"a\", aCode: \"b\", count: -2)" =     (
        "PAData(pCode: \"a\", aCode: \"b\", count: 2)",
        "PAData(pCode: \"a\", aCode: \"b\", count: 3)"
    );
    "PAData(pCode: \"d\", aCode: \"c\", count: -2)" =     (
        "PAData(pCode: \"d\", aCode: \"c\", count: 2)"
    );
}
Set:
{(
    PAData(pCode: "a", aCode: "b", count: 3),
    PAData(pCode: "d", aCode: "c", count: 2),
    PAData(pCode: "a", aCode: "b", count: 2)
)}
```

Comment: Sheesh calcSum2() seems to be fine - takes 0.1 seconds or so !!  Many thanks.  It's not really clear whether Set() when used with a struct will look at each property - even if the struct is Equatable or Hashable.  Having said that it seems to give the same summary total count as calcSum2().